# python xpath extract text outside tag based on the span text

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I want to extract the text outside the tag and match it with the text inside the span.

This is the code:

```
<div class="info">
    <p>
        <i class="icon-trending-up"></i>
        <span>Rank:</span>
        600
    </p>
    <p>
        <i class="icon-play"></i>
        <span>Total Videos:</span>
        36
    </p>
    <p>
        <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
        <span>Video Views:</span>
        1,815,767
    </p>
    <hr>
    <p>
        <i class="icon-user-plus"></i>
        <span>Followers:</span>
        732
    </p>
</div>
```

I want to extract something like this in separate items.

```
item['rank'] = rank

Rank: 600

item['videos'] = videos

Total Videos: 36

item['views'] = views 

Video Views: 1,815,767
```

I do not want the <*p*> tag below <*hr*>

This is what i have tried by now:

```
rank = response.xpath("//div[@class='info']//hr/preceding-sibling::p//text()='Videos:'").extract()
```

This is the result:

```
[u'0']
```

OR

```
rank = response.xpath("//div[@class='info']//hr/preceding-sibling::p/span[contains(text(), 'Videos:')]/text()|//hr/preceding-sibling::p//text()[not(parent::span)]").extract()
```

This is the result:

```
[u' 600', u'Total Videos:', u' 36', u' 1,815,767']
```

Basically i want to extract The number Based on the span Text, and every <*p*> tag separated in it's on item.

Thank you

***UPDATE***

I can't use anything like p[1], p[2] etc...because those <*p*> may swap, or it might be only 2 on other pages. The <*span*> text will remain the same

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
item["rank"] = response.xpath('//span[.="Rank:"]/following-sibling::text()[1]').extract_first()
item["videos"] = response.xpath('//span[.="Video Views:"]/following-sibling::text()[1]').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It looks a bit clumsy because it has to deal with the nested elements.

```
item['rank'] = ''.join(s.strip() for s in response.xpath('//div//span[contains(., "Rank:")]/ancestor::p/text()').extract())
```